# iTunes get Affiliate Token from code

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, itunes-store

Everyone! :)

I would like to be able to tell from the App where the user came from.

I found this article about affiliate links:
https://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/basic_affiliate_link_guidelines_for_the_phg_network.html

So it's possible to include affiliate token and campaign text in the iTunes link of the App.
However I would like to get these affiliate token and campaign text values from the code of the App.

Comment: When you say "where the user came from" do you mean how they eventually came to download your application? If that's the case certain ad networks, for instance AdMob, have conversion tracking abilities to see if the user actually did download your application based on an advertisement they saw. Also, the iTunes Affiliate Program you mentioned does not track where these links are clicked it just tracks the number of clicks and time. What you're looking to achieve isn't exactly possible.

Comment: What I would like to achieve is the following:
I make several links with different referring ids. I put different links to different pages that advertise my app.
In the app I would like to see where the user found the app by checking this referring id.
So there should be some kind of data that I can attach to a link I place on a page, that is persisted until the user runs the app, and I can check it from the app.

Answer (score 5):

You will not be able to access those values from within the app. They are not passed from the App Store in to the app that is installed. They are only available in the reporting dashboard.

Comment: Okay. Then how else can I achieve this:
There is a link like https://itunes.apple.com/app/my-app/id506489038?refer_data=123
And I would like to get the refer_data from within the app or any other field I can attach to the link.

Comment: There is _no way_ to get any install information within the app. They are all installed from the App Store, and that does't pass the information in. You can use web based analytics to see what they are pressing, and maybe even pull this from the server in to the app, but there won't be a way of tying X action to Y app.